# In Psalmi 102:2 in Vulgate, it says "et noli oblivisci _omnes retributiones_ ejus.". Shouldn't it be genitive (_omnium retributionium_) there?

Tags: vulgata

In Psalmi 102:2 in Vulgate, it says "*et noli oblivisci **omnes retributiones** ejus.*". Shouldn't it be genitive (*omnium retributionium*) there? I mean, "*oblivisci*" (to forget) goes with the genitive case, right?

Comment: Have you looked up *oblivisci* in a dictionary? Does it perhaps say anything about the accusative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb **[obliviscor](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dobliviscor)** can be used with both genitive *and* accusative, according to Lewis and Short. They provide examples from the Classical period for both, even by the same author, namely Cicero:

> **obliviscar noctis illius** ([Cic. Planc. 42.101](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0015%3Atext%3DPlanc.%3Achapter%3D42%3Asection%3D101))

> **obliviscor iam iniurias tuas** ([Cic. Cael. 20.50](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0010%3Atext%3DCael.%3Achapter%3D20%3Asection%3D50))